# fullcalendar doesnt load events

Tags: javascript, sql, json, events, fullcalendar

I am using dataJSON that i get from sql procedure as feed , and calendar loads but it doesnt get filled from it , the json format is proper i have tested it as static input , but when i put data as feed it just doesnt work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
callJsonWs("EXECUTE procedureName + some entry parametars ","loadPageGather");
});
```

After that i move to loadPageGather function that fills calendar

```
 function loadPageGather(dataJSON) {
        var data
        try {
            data = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert("ERROR - " + err.message)
        }


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: data.timetable,

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            resizable: true,
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            eventTextColor: '#3498db',

 eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
            var start = event.start.format()
            var end = event.end.format()
            var semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode = event.semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode
            var timetableCode = event.id
            eventUpdate(start, end, semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode, timetableCode)
        },

        // EVENT DELETE 

        eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent) {
            var semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode = event.semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode
            var timetableCode = event.id


            var trashEl = jQuery('#asideDiv');
            var ofs = trashEl.offset();

            var x1 = ofs.left;
            var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
            var y1 = ofs.top;
            var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);

            if (jsEvent.pageX >= x1 && jsEvent.pageX <= x2 &&
                jsEvent.pageY >= y1 && jsEvent.pageY <= y2) {

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                callJsonWs("dskrbic", "EXECUTE hereIs delete procedure);
            }
        },

        // EVENT RESIZE
        eventResize: function (event, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
            var start = event.start.format()
            var end = event.end.format()
            var semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode = event.semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode
            var timetableCode = event.id
            eventUpdate(start, end, semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode, timetableCode)
         });
```

This is the format of json i get :

```
{"timetable" : [    {"semesterStudyProgramUnitObligationCode":"20","id":"1","start":"2016-01-02T10:00:00","end":"2016-01-02T13:00:00","semesterName":"First","title":"OPERATIVNI SISTEMI - Lectures","description":"Kampus - Zgrada - Classroom - 12"},]}
```

I am newbie to this , am i doing it wrong ? Tell me your opinion , thanks

LITTLE UPDATE
For some reason if i put loadPageGather() after callJsonWs in document ready it works , and all of my functions work except part of asside is mising and asside meni doesnt work  , and if i remove it , it just loads calendar , and none of its calendar functionalities work (delete ,update and stuff) ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED by adding all of calendar functions , and loading to document ready , and in other function just filling the data by using :

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', data.timetable);
```